# Tabulator add a validator for two unique fields at once

Tags: tabulator

I tried to look for this option but I can't find much. What I need is a validator that checks if the union of two fields is unique. Is this possible with an already created option or do I need to create a custom validator?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom validator for this.

There is a guide on how to do this on the [Validator Docs](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/validate#func-custom)